# how to chage media soures by using sceentap gesture?

Tags: javafx-8, leap-motion

I want to change media source and restart mediaplayer in javafx by using leap motion gesture.

1. how to decribe screentap gesture case in LeapListener for restart mediaplayer?
2. hot to change media source by using swipe gesture?

and is there anything to fix plz help (I'm beginner in java & this is the first time of programming)

here is my code

public class Leaptest extends Application{

```
private final LeapListener listener = new LeapListener();
private final Controller leapcontroller = new Controller();
private Media media = new Media("file:///C:/Users/halim.shin/workspace/Movie/flower.mp4");
private MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
private MediaView view = new MediaView(player);


@Override
public void start(Stage Stage) throws Exception {
    leapcontroller.addListener(listener);
    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();


    int key_move_delta = 10;
    double size_delta = 1.05;   

    root.setCenter(view);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root,500,500,Color.BLACK);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm()); 

    scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch(event.getCode()){
                case UP             : view.setTranslateY(view.getTranslateY()   -   key_move_delta); break;
                case RIGHT          : view.setTranslateX(view.getTranslateX()   +   key_move_delta); break;
                case DOWN           : view.setTranslateY(view.getTranslateY()   +   key_move_delta); break;
                case LEFT               : view.setTranslateX(view.getTranslateX()   -   key_move_delta); break;
                case PAGE_UP        : view.setScaleX(view.getScaleX()*size_delta); view.setScaleY(view.getScaleY()*size_delta); break;
                case PAGE_DOWN  : view.setScaleX(view.getScaleX()/size_delta); view.setScaleY(view.getScaleY()/size_delta); break;
                case ENTER          : player.pause(); break;
                case SPACE          : player.play(); break;             
            }
        }   
    });

    player.setCycleCount(MediaPlayer.INDEFINITE);
    player.setMute(true);
//  player.play(); //

    Stage.setFullScreen(false);
    Stage.setScene(scene);
    Stage.show();   

}

public void stop(){
    leapcontroller.removeListener(listener);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    launch(args);
}
```

}

public class LeapListener extends Listener {

```
public void onConnect(Controller controller){
    controller.enableGesture(Gesture.Type.TYPE_SWIPE);
    controller.enableGesture(Gesture.Type.TYPE_CIRCLE);
    controller.enableGesture(Gesture.Type.TYPE_SCREEN_TAP); 
    controller.enableGesture(Gesture.Type.TYPE_KEY_TAP);
}

public void onFrame(Controller controller){



    Frame frame = controller.frame();
    GestureList gestures = frame.gestures();
    for(int i=0; i<gestures.count(); i++){
        Gesture gesture = gestures.get(i);

            **switch (gesture.type()){
            case TYPE_SCREEN_TAP :
            ??????????????????

                System.out.println("Key");
                break;
            default : 
                break;**

            }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You have to communicate two different threads: the JavaFX thread and the Leap Motion one.

For that, you can easily add `ObjectProperty<T>` objects to the `LeapListener` class in order to set desired values at every frame for given gestures. Then you have to implement their related public `ObservableValue<T>` methods.

On the JavaFX thread, an anonimous `ChangeListener<T>` class can be added to listen for any change in the `ObservableValue`. Note you'll have to use `Platform.runLater()`.

Starting with the `LeapListener` class:

```
public class LeapListener extends Listener {

    private final BooleanProperty keyTap= new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
    public BooleanProperty keyTapProperty() { return keyTap; }

    public enum DIRECTION { NONE,LEFT,RIGHT,UP,DOWN }
    public ObjectProperty<DIRECTION> swipeGesture=new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    @Override
    public void onConnect(Controller controller){
        controller.enableGesture(Gesture.Type.TYPE_KEY_TAP);
        controller.enableGesture(Gesture.Type.TYPE_SWIPE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFrame(Controller controller){

        Frame frame = controller.frame();

        // reset properties
        keyTap.set(false);
        swipeGesture.set(DIRECTION.NONE);

        GestureList gestures = frame.gestures();
        for(int i=0; i<gestures.count(); i++){
            Gesture gesture = gestures.get(i);
            switch (gesture.type()){
                case TYPE_SCREEN_TAP :
                    keyTap.set(true);
                    break;
                case TYPE_SWIPE: 
                    SwipeGesture swipe = new SwipeGesture(gesture);
                    if(Math.abs(swipe.direction().getX()) > 
                       Math.abs(swipe.direction().getY())){
                        if(swipe.direction().getX() > 0){
                            swipeGesture.set(DIRECTION.RIGHT);
                        } else {
                            swipeGesture.set(DIRECTION.LEFT);
                        }
                    } else {
                        if(swipe.direction().getY() > 0){
                            swipeGesture.set(DIRECTION.UP);
                        } else {
                            swipeGesture.set(DIRECTION.DOWN);
                        }                  
                    }
                    break;
                default : 
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While in your JavaFX class:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {

    ...

    LeapListener leapListener=new LeapListener();

    leapListener.keyTapProperty().addListener(
            (ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean t, final Boolean t1) -> {
        if(t1){
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                // React to Tap Gesture...
                player.play();
            });
        }
    });

    leapListener.swipeGesture.addListener(
       (ObservableValue<? extends LeapListener.DIRECTION> observable,
        LeapListener.DIRECTION oldValue, LeapListener.DIRECTION newValue) -> {
                Platform.runLater(()->{
                    // React to Swipe Gesture ...
                    switch(newValue){
                        case UP     : break;
                        case RIGHT  : break;
                        case DOWN   : break;
                        case LEFT   : break;
                    }
                });
    }); 

    player.setCycleCount(MediaPlayer.INDEFINITE);
    player.setMute(true);
//  player.play(); //

    stage.setFullScreen(false);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();   
}
```

Just note that whenever a Tap/Swipe gesture is detected by the Leap Motion controller, the properties are updated, and the listener is triggered. In the JavaFX thread now you can respond to that gestures.

Comment: Thank your for your help. I can complete the code by Copying your advice. But Still I cannot make a new move for another projects. Where can I get information for studying javafx and Leap motion?    Could you recommend something like books or website?

Comment: I guess this is not the place for recommending books or blogs, but you can easily find my work in regarding JavaFX and Leap Motion online :)